# Python nose test with relative pandas file path

Tags: python, relative-path, nose2

I am trying to write a unit test for a piece of code that includes using pandas to read a CSV file from a relative path. The directory structure is:

```
./
./thing1/main.py
./thing1/test_main.py
./thing1/dat/file.csv
./otherthings/...
```

In `main.py`, I have:

```
def doThings:
    pandas.read_csv('dat/file.csv')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    doThings()
```

In `test_main.py`, I have

```
class TestMain:
    def setup(self):
        doThings()

    def test_thing(self):
        pass  # there's other logic in here
```

Things work fine if I run `main.py`, but when I ask Anaconda to "run project tests", I get an IOError complaining that 'dat/file.csv' does not exist. It's related to the fact that it's a relative path, since when I change it to `/home/user/.../thing1/dat/file.csv`, it works. Is there a way that I can make the unit test work while keeping the relative path?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. If you call os.path.abspath() on your relative path you'll see that the absolute path is wrong. The only workaround I found was to change the relative path to absolute to the test file path by using __file__ and then moving up one level to exclude the file name:

```
testImgPath = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '../', 'testFiles', 'imgName.jpg'))
```

Comment: `as_absolute = lambda path: os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, "../", path))` !!! yess finallly. i've been messing with this for at least an hour.